# DataGridview cells of one column can't have different type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

well I have a datagridview , and i have a column, all i want to do is controlling the cells in this column, sometimes make it combobox, sometimes textBox ....etc

I can make the cells of a column have only one type , can i make many cells type in one column  ?

hope it is clear .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Cast a DataGridViewCell to a certain cell type that exists. For example, convert a DataGridViewTextBoxCell to DataGridViewComboBoxCell type.
2. Create a control and add it into the controls collection of DataGridView, set its location and size to fit the cell that to be host.

See my sample code below which illustrates the tricks.

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("name");
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add("");
            }
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;

            /*
             * First method : Convert to an existed cell type such ComboBox cell,etc
             */

            DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa","bbb","ccc" });
            this.dataGridView1[0, 0] = ComboBoxCell;
            this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "bbb";

            DataGridViewTextBoxCell TextBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            this.dataGridView1[0, 1] = TextBoxCell;
            this.dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "some text";

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CheckBoxCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
            CheckBoxCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.dataGridView1[0, 2] = CheckBoxCell;
            this.dataGridView1[0, 2].Value = true;

            /*
             * Second method : Add control to the host in the cell
             */
            DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
            dtp.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
            //add DateTimePicker into the control collection of the DataGridView
            this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(dtp);
            //set its location and size to fit the cell
            dtp.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Location;
            dtp.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Size;
        }
```

Taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/63ddb457-f769-44db-87cc-9e88e74929e8)