# Set DataGridView cell editor based on row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to have different cells in the same column to display/edit data differently?

I'm trying to use a data grid to let the user enter values for parameters specified in an XML file.  This would be fairly straightforward, except that some parameters are strings, some are integers, and some are booleans.

While I could just use a textbox with cell validating events to force the user to enter values that meet the criteria for the parameter, I think it would be more user-friendly to use a text box cell for String parameters, a checkbox cell for Boolean parameters, and a numeric up down cell (that I made) for Integer parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these possible solutions (which are all very similar):

1. [How to host different controls in the same column in DataGridView control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/63ddb457-f769-44db-87cc-9e88e74929e8/)
2. [Windows Forms DataGridView control have different control types in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986233/windows-forms-datagridview-control-have-different-control-types-in-the-same-colu)
3. [DataGridview cells of one column can't have different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055918/datagridview-cells-of-one-column-cant-have-different-type)

The first one looks like a working sample, according to the comments.