# Adding Different DataGridView Cell Types to a Column

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, cells

### Goal

My datagridview has two columns ([Question], [Answer]). Depending on the known **question type** (**Yes/No** *Checkbox*, **Text** *Textbox*, **FileUpload** *Button*) I want the column cell to have the respective *control*.

**Example**

Datagridview Rows:

1. [Question] Do you smoke? [Answer] (**YesNo** *Checkbox*)
2. [Question] How old are you? [Answer] (**Text** *Textbox*)
3. [Question] Document upload [Answer] (**FileUpload** *Button*)

---

### Work

I programmatically create my datagridviews.

```
Private Sub FormatQuestionDgv(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    Dim ColQ As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Dim ColA As New DataGridViewColumn

    'Header text
    ColQ.HeaderText = "Question"
    ColA.HeaderText = "Answer"

    'Name
    ColQ.Name = "ColQ"
    ColA.Name = "ColA"

    'Widths
    ColQ.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    ColA.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill

    'Add columns
    With dgv.Columns
        .Add(ColQ)
        .Add(ColA)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### Problem

As you can see in my work, the answer column is of `DataGridViewColumn` type. I do not know the question type at that moment. Therefore I declare it as a normal column instead of `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, `DataGridViewButtonColumn`...

Since those are not the same type as `DataGridViewColumn`, I get the following error:

[image: Wrong Type Error]

How do I go about adding different control types in 1 DataGridViewColumn? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you looked at these:

[Mixing cell types in a DataGridViewColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631612/mixing-cell-types-in-a-datagridviewcolumn)

[DataGridview cells of one column can't have different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055918/datagridview-cells-of-one-column-cant-have-different-type)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/148b232b-ce8c-4c49-b35d-50d8a5c448d1/different-cell-types-in-a-datagridview-column

Following from the MSDN article...

There are two ways to do this:

1. Cast a `DataGridViewCell` to a certain cell type that exists. For
   example, convert a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` to
   `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` type.
2. Create a control and add it into the controls collection of
   `DataGridView`, set its location and size to fit the cell that to be
   host.

Here's some sample code which illustrates these tricks:

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("name");
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add("");
    }
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;

    /*
     * First method : Convert to an existed cell type such ComboBox cell,etc
     */

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa","bbb","ccc" });
    this.dataGridView1[0, 0] = ComboBoxCell;
    this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "bbb";

    DataGridViewTextBoxCell TextBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    this.dataGridView1[0, 1] = TextBoxCell;
    this.dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "some text";

    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CheckBoxCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
    CheckBoxCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    this.dataGridView1[0, 2] = CheckBoxCell;
    this.dataGridView1[0, 2].Value = true;

    /*
     * Second method : Add control to the host in the cell
     */
    DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
    dtp.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
    //add DateTimePicker into the control collection of the DataGridView
    this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(dtp);
    //set its location and size to fit the cell
    dtp.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Location;
    dtp.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Size;
}
```

Comment: Yes I searched for those links before but I thought there was an easier way of doing so.

Comment: also I think the msdn link is pretty straight forward method

Comment: Yes I'm directly showing it on the UI so that the user can answer questions. Yes the MDSN link is easy to follow. Thank you

Comment: This doesn't work in VS 2013. I get all textbox cells.

Comment: @puneet, first method doesn't work if datagridview is on another form. And second method has an issue with datagridview scrollbar. Any solution for these problems?

Comment: I don't know about the rest of you, but I got an error "Formatted value of the cell has a wrong type" until I added these lines:              CheckBoxCell.IndeterminateValue = false;
 CheckBoxCell.FalseValue = false;
 CheckBoxCell.TrueValue = true;
Or just CheckBoxCell.ValueType = typeof(bool);

Answer (score 7):

> The other answers are way to difficult and error prone.
> It is way easier to add the required cell type upon request.

**Example:**

Using the designer, create a form with a DataGridView, and two columns: one for the question and one for the answer.

```
private DataGridView dataGridView3;
private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnQuestion;
private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnAnswer;
```

In my class, I created the enum for the answer type

```
public enum AnswerType
{
    Text,
    YesNo,
    LoadFile,
    Combo,              
};
```

I create two methods: one to create a cell that contains a question, and one to create the proper cell type for the answer.

The method to create a question cell is simple:

```
private DataGridViewCell CreateQuestionCell(string question)
{
    return new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
    {
        ValueType = typeof(string),
        Value = question,
        ReadOnly = true,       // questions can't be edited
    };
}
```

The method to create an answer cell has a parameter indicating the desired answer type:

```
private DataGridViewCell CreateAnswerCell(AnswerType answerType)
{
    // type of column depends on rowIndex
    DataGridViewCell cell;
    switch (answerType)
    {
        case AnswerType.YesNo: // Create a checkbox cell
            cell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
            {
                ValueType = typeof(bool),
                Value = false,
            };
            break;
        case AnswerType.LoadFile: // Create a Button cell
            cell = new DataGridViewButtonCell()
            {
                ValueType = typeof(string),
                Value = "Load!",
            };
            break;
        case AnswerType.Combo: // Create a Combo Cell
            var selectableValues = Enumerable.Range(0, 4);
            var comboItems = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);
            cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell()
            {
                DataSource = new BindingList<int>(comboItems.ToList()),
            };
            break;
        default: // Create a Text cell
            cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
            {
                ValueType = typeof(string),
                Value = "<please enter name>",
            };
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Upon request add a Row, containing a question cell and an answer cell:

```
private void AddRow(string question, AnswerType answerType)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    row.Cells.Add(this.CreateQuestionCell(question));
    row.Cells.Add(this.CreateAnswerCell(answerType));
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

To test I created four buttons and handlers to add rows:

```
private Button buttonCheckbox;
private Button buttonAction;
private Button buttonCombo;
private Button buttonText;

private void OnButtonCheckbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AddRow("Do you smoke", AnswerType.YesNo);
}

private void OnButtonText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AddRow("Name", AnswerType.Text);
}

private void OnButtonCombo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AddRow("Age?", AnswerType.Combo);
}

private void OnButtonAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AddRow("Document upload", AnswerType.LoadFile);
}
```

Et voilà, ça marche! Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: Haha merci!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGridViewCellStyle styl_Column = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
         if (_myColumnCollection[i].TypeColumn == TypColumn.CheckBox)
                {
                   dtv_information.Columns.Add(chk_clmn);
                   styl_Column.NullValue = false;

                }
styl_Column.NullValue = false;
```