# How to Disable or Hide Button in DataGridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, xampp

Hi I want to Hide or Disable the button in my 3rd column which I intend to add row every time I click it. The mess is, the previous buttons are active and can add row. How can I place the button only in the last row?

Here's my working code:

```
    Private Sub dgAppliances_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgAppliances.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex <> 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If Me.dgAppliances.RowCount - 1 = 20 Then
            MsgBox("Maximum of 20 appliances only.")
        Else
            Me.dgAppliances.Rows.Add()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But when I added some codes:

```
    Private Sub dgAppliances_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgAppliances.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex <> 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If Me.dgAppliances.RowCount - 1 = 20 Then
            MsgBox("Maximum of 20 appliances only.")
        Else
            Me.dgAppliances.Rows.Add()
            Dim cell As DataGridViewButtonCell = dgAppliances.Rows(0).Cells(2)
            cell.Value = String.Empty
            cell = New DataGridViewColumn()
            cell.ReadOnly = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This line cell = New DataGridViewColumn() has an error.

It says, 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonCell'.

Can anyone help me about this? TIA.

[Here's the sample image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB7Lc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign a `DataGridViewColumn` into a `DataGridViewButtonCell` - an entire *column* to a single *cell*.

Perhaps your intention was: `cell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()`? But even then, if you're trying to

> place the button only in the last row

Then you're going to run into the problem of [Adding Different DataGridView Cell Types to a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18045248/3773066). You could do the conversion as seen below:

```
Me.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3
Me.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
Me.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
Me.dataGridView1.RowCount = 1
Me.dataGridView1(2, 0) = New DataGridViewButtonCell()

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If TypeOf Me.dataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonCell Then
        If Me.dataGridView1.RowCount - 1 = 20 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Maximum of 20 appliances only.")
        Else
            Me.dataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            Me.dataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
            Me.dataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).[ReadOnly] = True
            Me.dataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, Me.dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) = New DataGridViewButtonCell()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Woah. You're the best!! Thank you so much for the help. :))) It works, I'm working on making the previous rows to delete button. :) Thank you so much, hope you can help me on it too. :)

Comment: In that case, you don't need to convert the cell at all.  Make the column a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` from the start.  Then in your `CellContentClick` event, if you clicked a `DataGridViewButtonCell`, check if it's the last row in the grid.  If it is, add another row.  If it is not, delete the clicked row.  The only part you'll have to play with is changing the button text from "Add" to "Delete".

Comment: I got it sir. Thank you again. :))